# TLS in Smack when connecting to XMPP server

Tags: android, sockets, ssl, xmpp, smack

I am trying to connect to Firebase Cloud Messaging CCS. I am using Smack that needs to establish a secure TLS connection and then authenticate via a SASLMechanism "Plain". I've done extensive reading on the subject and found out that first you must establish TLS and then authenticate with a "Plain" SASLMechanism. I am sort of stuck on the TLS part. I created a "csr" - certificate signing request with java keytool. The "csr" was successfully signed by GeoTrust.com, however I had to first register a domain under my name in order to obtained this signed certificate. So, I guess that certificate is validated for my domain name, but I am trying to use it for establishing a TLS connection with "FCM". The certificate comes with two intermediate certificates. Each of the three certificate have been saved under my Assets folder as text files in my Android Studio. The certificates are uploaded correctly in my Android code, however I've read that it is better to use a BufferedReader. Here's how I upload my certificates:

```
try {
input = manager.open("certi");
input1 = manager.open("certii");
input2 = manager.open("certiii");
InputStream caInput = new BufferedInputStream(input);
InputStream stream1 = new BufferedInputStream(input1);
InputStream stream2 = new BufferedInputStream(input2);
Certificate ca,ca1, ca2;
try {
cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
cf1 = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
cf2 = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
ca1 = cf1.generateCertificate(stream1);
ca2 = cf2.generateCertificate(stream2);
InterfaceClass.certificate = ca;
InterfaceClass.inter_certificate1 = ca1;
InterfaceClass.inter_certificate2 = ca2;
```

Now, from what I've read its better to load a certificate like this:

```
InputStream caInput = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("load-der.crt"));  //NOTICE THE FILEINPUTSTREAM USED I USE INPUTSTREAM
//INPUT,INPUT1,INPUT2
```

I also create a keystore for each of the three certificates like this:

```
//I do this three times cause each keystore will have one different
//certificate   
String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
try {
keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
keyStore.load(null, null);
keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", InterfaceClass.certificate);

//creating a trustmanagerfactory
String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
TrustManagerFactory tmf = null;
try {
tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
//initializing the keystore with the tmf
try {
tmf.init(keyStore); //do this three times for keystore1, keystore2
TrustManager[] trust = tmf.getTrustManagers();
int size = trust.length;
Log.d("trusti","first: "+size);// i expect to get size = 3 but size =1 WHY?
//CREATING AN SSLCONTEXT FOR MY SMACK CONFIGURATIONBUILDER OBJECT
SSLContext context = null;
try {
context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
```

now from the above code, why is size = 1 , I thought it would be 3 since i initialized three different keystores which hold three different certificates?
Perhaps this is why I get the following exception:
***javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.***

I don't think my configurationbuilder object for my smack connection is getting all the three certificates it needs to establish TLS with "FCM". How can I do this? I tried creating one keystore with three different certificates, didn't work. I tried copy and pasting all three certificates in the same Assets text file and creating one certificate with that text file and one keystore, it didnt work either. How can I get more trust managers in my trustmanagerfactory object?

Also, how should i use this SSlcontext object in my connection: This is how I've tried, which way would be best:

```
//way 1
configBuilder.setCustomSSLContext(context);
//way 2
configBuilder.setSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
```

**An error that I received has useful information the error is as follows: at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.initReaderAndWriter(XMPPTCPConnection.java:655)** when I cliked on line 655 it brought me to one of Smack's internal method calls. This is telling me that somehow the inputstream is not being read in the socket. I guess the socket can't read my inputstream that has all my three certificates that's why I cant establish a trust anchor validation path. Here's what Smack's internal method call looks like:

```
private void initReaderAndWriter() throws IOException {
InputStream is = socket.getInputStream(); //ERROR THROWN HERE
```

Does my SSlcontext object communicate with this socket. How can i access this socket in code in order to make it find my trust certificates?

Also, what would be the best setting for my connection: I've tried both, but still get errors:

```
//way1
configBuilder.setSecurityMode(XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.required);
configBuilder.setServiceName("fcm-xmpp.googleapis.com");
configBuilder.setHost("fcm-xmpp.googleapis.com"); 
configBuilder.setPort(5236);
configBuilder.setCompressionEnabled(false); 
configBuilder.setSendPresence(false);/SHOULD THIS BE TRUE
configBuilder.setUsernameAndPassword("senderID"+"@gcm.googleapis.com",      serverKey);
XMPPTCPConnection.setUseStreamManagementDefault(true); //WHAT IS THIS FOR
XMPPTCPConnection.setUseStreamManagementResumptionDefault(true);//???
FCMconnection = new   XMPPTCPConnection(TLSUtils.setTLSOnly(configBuilder).build());//NOTICE HERE

//way2: everything same as way1 but these two lines:
configBuilder.setSecurityMode(XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);
FCMconnection = new XMPPTCPConnection(configBuilder.build());
```

Please help me in sorting this stuff out. After this, I will have to deal with SASLMechanism authentication on Smack with "FCM". Hope that goes more smoothly than TLS. Again, any adivce or suggestions many thanks.

Comment: did you find a solution? I'm trying to move from GCM CCS to FCM and haven't been able to get an authorized connection yet (luckily not a production environment yet)

Comment: Got it working without setting up any specific TLS information. The issue happened when we changed the Host Name to the FCM endpoint, that our code also added the same host name to the sender id as login name. That looks to not have changed, so the login name should stay as senderid@gcm.googleapis.com

Comment: So you connected to FCM CCS without TLS? I got rid of the error that says it couldnt find the trust anchor path. Which means my keystore was initialized and its path was found by Smack. Am trying to do authentication with SASLMechanism on Smack's library. Check my newest question i just posted. Maybe we can work together on resolving these issues. If you want to know how to upload keystore and get rid of "trust anchor not found error" let me know. For production you would want to establish TLS handshake. @Quintium

Comment: No, it is using TLS. I assigning the XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration configuration, I use a default SSL factory like this (in Java): setSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory.getDefault())
- It can be discussed if production worthy, but should be good enough on secure servers (We use AWS environment) unless you are really worried on message capturing. We use it only to send reference keys to the app for the app to communicate with our web services to get the true message (a lot of times larger than the allowed payload size for FCM messages)

Comment: Ok. So how did you perform SaslAuthentication with FCM CCS. Am trying to do that now? @Quintium

Comment: I'm not setting anything like that up specifically. I have seen there used to be a setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(bool) for XMPPConnection, but not required by XMPPTCPConnection. All I do is following: XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder().setServiceName(serviceName).setHost(host).setSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory.getDefault()).setSendPresence(false).setPort(port).setConnectTimeout(60000).build();  Then connect and then login by senderid@gcm... and Sever App Key as password.

Comment: I've been trying to do that using Smack 4.1 but it doesnt work. For setHost and setServiceName i use "fcm-xmpp.googleapis.com" and setPort I use 5236. What values do you use for sethost and setservicename and your port number. Thanks  @Quintium  Also, what Smack version are you using?

Comment: I am using the same host name. Went straight ahead on port 5235, but the sandbox should work the same. If it helps this is the original GCM example I followed to create the service: https://github.com/googlesamples/friendlyping/blob/master/server/Java/src/main/java/com/gcm/samples/friendlyping/GcmServer.java